# How create single transaction kafka producer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When I read kafka docs :

> Setting setTransactionIdPrefix(String) enables transactions; in which case, a cache of producers is maintained; closing a producer returns it to the cache. The producers are closed and the cache is cleared when the factory is destroyed, the application context stopped, or the reset() method is called.

I understand that kafka creates a cache of producers. But how can i say kafka to create only one producer and use it instead of cache of producers. Maybe in spring boot exist some properties that can reduce the number of producers?

Comment: Producers are thread-safe, so only one is needed anyway. Not sure why a cache would be necessary

Comment: spring boot kafka config with TransactionIdPrefix create cache o producers by it self. So i try to understand how i can say spring boot to create only one producer instead of cache producers